# Automatically saving doc file after 20 secs

Tags: php

i am doing a php program which requires doc file to be saved after every 10 secs.msword should not ask the path to be saved. actually i have written a program which opens a doc file. the file should be auto saved to the exact location from where the file is opened.

Comment: msword should not ask the path to be saved. What do you mean with that ?
As I see the best solution is to use Ajax with a setInterval();

Comment: This makes no sense from a PHP perspective. Are you writing a web application? How does MS Word play into it? Needs much, much more info and a detailed description of how this file is being opened from where, possibly even some code

Comment: Do you mean that the web application should push a doc file to the user every 10 seconds, without asking for user confirmation? Sorry, but that's not possible.

Comment: here what i have written                                                                       if(is_file("file name"))
 $convert_file = "file loc";                                                                      then i have given the link to $convert_file..when it is clicked it open a msword file...but when i am trying to save that file...its asks for location..msword should save file to the same directory from where it is opened

Comment: the client side interaction you want is not possible with a server side language such as php, and even with client side languages there s are limits.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand you correctly, what you want to do is not possible (sadly).

There is no standard or protocol for live editing of remote files that have been downloaded from a web page in a browser. The file will be downloaded to a temporary location and opened from there.

Hence, any notion  of providing an auto-save mechanism from PHP or JavaScript is completely impossible. The client application will have to do that.

If you want to upload the downloaded and locally edited file back to the web site, you will need to provide an upload form for the user to do it manually. (Which is a shame and completely unintuitive, but that's the way technology is at the moment.)

Answer (score -2):

Not possible due to security reason in web technology.